# Comparing 2d arrays together

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have four 2d arrays of varying lengths. Is there a way to compare them to make sure none of the arrays share a value? Is there a simple way to code it or a gem I could use?

To back my question up with an example:

```
array1 = [[2,3],[2,4]]

array2 = [[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]

array3 = [[5,3],[6,3],[7,3],[8,3],[9,3]]
```

I want a checker that would let me know that `array1` and `array2` have an element the same.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it as follows.

**Code**

```
def shared_values?(*arr)
  a = arr.map(&:uniq).reduce(:+)
  a.size > a.uniq.size
end
```

**Examples**

```
array1 = [[2, 3], [2, 4]]
array2 = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
array3 = [[5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3],[8, 3],[9, 3]]
shared_values? array1, array2, array3 #=> true

array1 = [[2, 4]]
shared_values? array1, array2, array3 #=> false  

array1 = [[2, 4], [2, 4]]
shared_values? array1, array2, array3 #=> false

array1 = [[2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 4]]
shared_values? array1, array2, array3 #=> false
```

**Explanation**

For the last example above:

```
arr = [array1, array2, array3]
  #=> [ [[2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 4]],
  #     [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]],
  #     [[5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3], [8, 3], [9, 3]] ]

a = arr.map(&:uniq)
  #=> [ [[2, 3], [2 ,4]],
  #     [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]],
  #     [[5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3], [8, 3], [9, 3]] ]
b = a.reduce(:+)
  #=>   [[2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3],
  #      [5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3], [8, 3], [9, 3]]
c = b.uniq
  #=>   [[2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 3],         [3, 3],
  #      [5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3], [8, 3], [9, 3]]
b.size > c.size
  # 10 > 9 #=> true
```

`arr.map(&:uniq)` is the same as:

```
arr.map { |a| a.uniq }
```

`a.reduce(:+)` uses the form of [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) that takes an argument that is a symbol, naming a method to be applied to each element of `arr`, the result being the sum of the three arrays that comprise the elements of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are in a consistent format, like all numbers and not a mix of floating point and strings, you can do this:

```
array1 & array2
# => [[2, 3]]
```

That means to test if they overlap:

```
(array1 & array2).any?
```

If you can be assured each of the elements in all of the arrays are unique, then you can test quickly if there are any duplicates:

```
sum = array1 + array2 + array3 + array4
sum.length == sum.uniq.length
```

If each array *may* contain duplicates then you'd need to pair them off and compare A vs. B for all possible pairs.

Comment: For documentation on `&` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-26

Comment: Superior solution.  By the way, it will work on arrays with elements of mixed type.  All that is required is that each element has #hash? and #eql?.  Numbers and strings will work fine.

Comment: The OP said there are four arrays. Will you not have to do six pairwise comparisons?

Comment: If the arrays may themselves have duplicates (not specified), your need `sum = array1.uniq + ...`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I like your solution here, but you might want to explain your code a bit better. It's terse, which is great, but also hard to read for a beginner.